# MongoDB full text search and the aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, twitter

I am currently using the full-text search capabilities of MongoDB to count the number of documents per hour which contain a certain keyword.

This is really interesting when run across a large collection where each document is a Tweet. For example for the keyword "thanks" we see Nov 29 (Thanks Giving).

[image]

My current approach works (it generated the above plot) but it is not going to scale. At the moment I manually count the number of tweets in each hour by iterating over the documents returned by search. This approach is not going to scale as this search result will eventually reach the MongoDB document limit. At the moment it works because I have only 3.5 million tweets but I plan on collecting a lot more.

```
data = db.command('text', collection, 
  search=query,
  project={'hour_bucket': 1, '_id': 0},
  limit=-1
)

hours = Counter()
  for d in data['results']:
    hours[d['obj']['hour_bucket']] += 1
```

My question is: can text-search be used inside the aggregation pipeline? This would fix all of my problems. However the only comment I have seen about this is the following: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9063

Does anyone know what the status of this work is?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat coincidentally, support for text search in the aggregation framework has recently been committed with a tagged fixVersion for the upcoming MongoDB 2.5.5 development/unstable release (see [SERVER-11675](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11675)).

Assuming all goes well in QA/testing, this feature will be included in the 2.6 production release.

There should be some further information included in the [draft 2.6 release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/) after 2.5.5 is released, and I would encourage you to test this feature in your development environment.

FYI, you can find or subscribe to release announcements via the [`mongodb-announce` discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mongodb-announce).

Answer (score 0):

Manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/

Example:

```
db.tweets.aggregate(
    [   
        {   $match   : { $text: { $search: "query" } } },
        {   $project : { day  : { $substr: ["$created_at", 0, 10]}}},        
        {   $group   : { _id  : "$day",  number : { $sum : 1 }}},
        {   $sort    : { _id  : 1 }}        
    ]
)
```